# How to insert in data without image in a database that has an image column?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying for days but I just can't someone please help me.

My mySql database has an image column, and whenever I input data without an image it won't input the data. There might be a problem with my code but I don't know what to put. I need to be able to input data even if the user doesn't put an image in the picture box. Thank you!

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblMembers(name, contactno, address, birthday, baptism, ministry, memberpic)VALUES('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtContactNo.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & dtpBirthday.Text & "','" & dtpBaptism.Text & "','" & txtMinistry.Text & "',@memberpic)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@memberpic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Save record successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Save")
        Clear()
    End If
    cn.Close()
    ShowRecord()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we get the output of `DESC tblMembers` from MySQL?

Comment: @Pachonk what do you mean `DESC tblMembers`?

Comment: Open your database console, simply type `desc tblMembers;`. Copy/paste results into your answer.

Comment: @Pachonk How do I open the database console? Sorry im a noob but I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `mysql -u{username}-p {database}` on the cli should do it. Obviously fill in username and database with YOUR username and database;

Comment: @Pachonk `mysql -u{TANSENGCO\SQLEXPRESS}-p {MonitoringSystem}`

Comment: Don't actually use the curlies

Comment: I just want to know the create table clause. Or a describe of the table.

Comment: Either way, with your posted error on the other answer, this isn't a database issue.

Comment: @Pachonk Yes it's not. It's on my VB code. If I don't choose/input an image along with the other data. I get an error. Think you can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap line 5 of your snippet with an if. The if should be something like "if image was uploaded" or "if a.fileName is not null"

Comment: Thanks, but what do I put in-case they didn't choose a photo? This error shows up.  *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@memberpic".*